# Mining calculators and blocks found

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability

Whenever we use an online mining calculator, do these calculator estimate a 100% blocks finding? Shouldn't they be subject to the pool efficiency and how many blocks are found? I mean, if my pool only catches 50% of total blocks my mining earnings are cut in half. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

No, your earnings are related to how much hashing power *you* contribute to the network, not your share of the pool's hashing power.

Said differently, if you were mining solo and providing an infinite amount of time, the earnings would be the same (minus the fees). Pools only exist to give you more frequent, smaller revenue.

Comment: Yeah but I'm not talking about pools. Let's say it's just you and me and I own 1/10 of the total hashrate. It is a matter of probability I'll finding 1/10 blocks and therefore earning 1/10 of total rewards, right?

Comment: Correct, over a certain period of time. As I said, your earnings are related to how much hashing power you contribute to the network.